# Load pixel data from image in Office scripts

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

I want to fetch a png image from the web, and then load all the pixels inside typescript such that I can modify the image per pixel. Since this concerns an Excel Office script, I can not use the often mentioned "context.getImageData()".

I tried to transform the response to an Uint8Array, and read the integers. I however do not understand how to use this data. In total, it has a length of 235.597. The image has a size of 3150 x 2513 pixels. As of my understanding, this would mean there would be 3150 x 2513 x 4 (4 since RGBA) = 7.915.950 values to represent the full image.

In short: How can I load pixel data from a PNG image that is fetched from the web within Office scripts?

The code I am using to get the array:

```
async function downloadImage(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const url = "Link to image"
    const res = await fetch(url)
    const data = await res.arrayBuffer();
    const img = new Uint8Array(data)
```

The length of Uint8Array is equal to 235597.

Comment: What's your final goal with png image?

Comment: Eventually, I want to put the image in the Excel sheet. However, before doing so certain colors need to be replaced, to do this I planned on iterating over all pixels and checking their color.

Comment: Please include your code in OP.

Comment: I think I answered another related question from you. Please see if that helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77252686/6656547