# Transform an array of pixels to an image within Office scripts

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

Within Office scripts I want to transform a 2D array of RGB pixels into an image. So for example, an array of a 4 pixel image could be:

```
[[[255,255,255],[0,0,0]],
[[255,255,255],[0,0,0]]]
```

I want to transform this array into an image in Office script. Within Javascript, I can only find solutions for doing this while using a canvas or external libraries. However, these are not available within Office script.

Within the Office script, there is the possiblity to display a base64 encoded image using:

```
const response = await fetch(link_to_sample_image);
const data = await response.arrayBuffer();
 const image = convertToBase64(data);
workbook.getWorksheet("ExampleSheet").addImage(image);
```

How can I transform an array with pixel data to an image that can be used within the Office Script addImage function?

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like node-canvas and draw the image onto the canvas as a Uint8Array with putImageData, and then turn the canvas into a base64 data url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution (**Please note this approach will only work when running Office Scripts in Excel for the Web and will fail when running the script in Power Automate!!!**):

- Convert your 2D array of RGB pixels into a linear 1D array of RGBA pixels of type `Uint8ClampedArray`.

  - The expected content of this `Uint8ClampedArray` is like `[R, G, B, A, R, G, B, A, ...]`. So every 4 consecutive elements in this array represent one pixel's R, G, B values and its Alpha channel.
  - If you don't need to consider transparency, you can always use `255` as the Alpha value for each of the pixel.
  - So basically you just need to flatten your original 2D RGB pixel array into a 1D array but inserting a `255` alpha channel after every 3 elements (R, G, B).
  - You can refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray) for more about `Uint8ClampedArray`.
- Now imagine a variable named `rgbArray` is your original 2D RGB pixels array. You can then write the following code to insert an image into the workbook with Office Scripts:

  ```js
  const rgbArray: number[][][] = 
    [
      [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]],
      [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]],
      [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]],
      [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]],
      [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]],
      [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]],
      [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]],
      [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]],
      [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]],
      [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]],
      [[255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0]],
    ];

  async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): Promise<void> {
    const imageHeight = rgbArray.length;
    const imageWidth = rgbArray[0].length;
    const pixels = new Uint8ClampedArray(4 * imageHeight * imageWidth);
    for (let y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++) {
        pixels[y * imageWidth * 4 + x * 4] = rgbArray[y][x][0];
        pixels[y * imageWidth * 4 + x * 4 + 1] = rgbArray[y][x][1];
        pixels[y * imageWidth * 4 + x * 4 + 2] = rgbArray[y][x][2];
        pixels[y * imageWidth * 4 + x * 4 + 3] = 255;
      }
    }

    const imageData = new ImageData(pixels, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    const canvas = new globalThis.OffscreenCanvas(imageWidth, imageHeight);
    const context2d = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context2d.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    const blob = await canvas.convertToBlob({ type: "image/png", quality: 1 });
    const dataUrl = new FileReaderSync().readAsDataURL(blob);
    const base64Data = dataUrl.split(";base64,")[1];
    const newImage = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().addImage(base64Data);
  }
  ```

For example, this sample Office Scripts transforms a 2D RGB pixels array of a smiley face into an image inserted into a workbook: https://gist.github.com/yutao-huang/98396e7a3b21fbfc4c8d914f7936f7cb.

[image: A smiley face image inserted into Excel worksheet]